# What is the Esc/Pos Epson thermal printer command to set 58mm roll width?

Tags: thermal-printer, epson, escpos

I have to control a thermal printer Epson TM-T20 with raw ESC/POS command.

Usually I work with 80mm roll and I don't need to set particular command or configuration. Now I need to prepare a template for a 58mm roll and I guess I need to tell the printer the printer width, for sure, I need it to use the `ESC a` (text align) command to print centered text.

Does anyone can tell me how to handle width with these printers?

Answer (score 0):

**rewritten with correct information**

You can use these commands.

[GS ( E <Function 1>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=229#gs_lparen_ce_fn01)
[GS ( E <Function 5>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=233#gs_lparen_ce_fn05)
[GS ( E <Function 2>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=230)

However, vendors do provide configuration tools for these uses and make them available for download.
It's safer and more reliable to use this configuration tool.
[TM-T20 Utility](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=3960&pcat=3&pid=37)

Comment: Sorry, why such info are private? Esc commands are published with technical printer docs in the manufacturer website.