# How to get the printer width, printer dpi using ESC/POS commands

Tags: android, kotlin, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to query the printer width and printer dpi from a thermal receipt printer using ESC/POS commands in android kotlin, and I find it really hard to find the relevant ESC/POS commands from the existing openly available documentation. Any idea of what ESC/POS commands that can be used for this requirement? Or else any other feasible solutions to query these values from the printer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands.

[GS ( E <Function 6>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=234)

> Transmits the customized value specified by a.

| a | Type of customized value |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Paper width |

---

The dpi is hardware information, will never change, and will be uniquely determined by the printer model number.
You should be able to identify it based on the information you can get with this command.

[GS I](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=198)

> Transmits the printer ID or printer information.

| n | Printer ID | Specification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1, 49 | Printer model ID | Printer model |
| 2, 50 | Type ID | Printer type |

---

Please refer to the linked document and others for more information.

---

By the way, here is the article of the command for setting.
[What is the Esc/Pos Epson thermal printer command to set 58mm roll width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74959678/9014308)

Comment: Yeah I tried these commands. But no response from the printer. I guess these commands are only for setting the values not for querying information

Comment: There is another command to set the value as introduced at the end of the answer. Are your system (hardware and OS) and application programs able to receive data sent from the printer?
And does your printer support the commands I wrote in my answer? Printers from vendors other than EPSON may not support them. If you do not meet all of these conditions one by one, you will not be able to obtain information.